# 20.04 display flickering with AMD Drivers

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I have a 5700XT. I installed the official drivers from AMD. After that my screen started flickering. I uninstalled the drivers using the uninstall script `./amdgpu-install --uninstall`, but the flickering persists. It would seem to me that the uninstall script did not actually revert everything to how it was before the driver installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary fix is to run this command:

> xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 1024x768; sleep 1; xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 2560x1440 -r 120

Replace the 2560x1440 -r 120 with your own resolution and refresh rate. This will stop the flickering immediately, but it will probably resume when you reboot or wake from sleep.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a directory `sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`
2. Create a file `20-radeon.conf` within that, `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-radeon.conf`
3. Write

[image]

Save the file and then reboot

Hope this helps

Comment: This fixes screen tearing but doesn't help with screen flickering.

Comment: It looks like they are using the amdgpupro or amdgpu-pro dirver instead of radeon

Answer (score 0):

I also used the amd 5700xt TUF OC 8Gb with Ubuntu 20.04.

Using the terminal I installed `all open variant`, because of some
needed parts from AMDGPU-PRO packs (for example: OpenCL).

I have no problems with the Installation. I play in Steam (Linux) Dying_light, Doom, Dirt Rally 4 or the newer 2.0, with nearby 200 Fps. A great Vulkan Support from this Card.

I search a graphical xserver_app for amdgpu settings. The Adrenalin Software in MS Windows IS AWESOME. Here is the terminal command I used:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy
```